# Get textfield values from JavaScript driven form and append those values to a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to grab two textfield values on button submit and then insert them into some HTML and append that HTML to a div.

[The test page](http://seafoammedia.com/dealer/quote/form.php) with the main javascript file being jtracker.js

The code I've inserted into jtracker.js to try and do this is:

```
$('.jtWidgetGetQuote').click(function(){
    $("#map").append("<img src='http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?maptype=roadmap&amp;markers=size:mid|color:red|"+ fieldNames['origZip'] +"|"+ fieldNames['destZip'] +"&amp;size=270x170&amp;sensor=true' alt='' />")
                            })
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried document.getElementById('yourdiv').innerHTML?

Comment: No not yet -- how would I implement that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to read content/value from two text boxes and add some HTML to that and insert that as the content of a div

**HTML**

```
City<input type="text" id="txtCity"/><br/>
Zip <input type="text" id="txtZip" /><br/>
<a href="#" id="a1">Go</a><br/>
<input type="button" id="btnGo" value="Go Button" />
<div id="div1"></div>
```

**Javsascript**  (Assuming you are using jQuery)

```
 $("#a1,#btnGo").click(function(){
    var htmlStr="<b>"+$("#txtCity").val()+"</b><br/><i>"+$("#txtZip").val()+"</i>";
    $("#div1").html(htmlStr); 
});
```

UPDATE: As per the comment, I updated the code to have a button to do the same as the link.

Here is the working demo http://jsfiddle.net/F4aYw/14/

Comment: OK - I got the code working but when I put it on the actual form page, it stops... http://seafoammedia.com/dealer/quote/form.php

Comment: Have your button some id and use that id in the javascript code. It will work. by the way, your page works for me

Comment: I did that with the button but the page isn't working for me... I'm wanting a map to show up in #map